# Calling C++ method from QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

**HERE IS Qt PROJECT with minimal skeleton to show what is the problem (check console after you run that project)**
http://uloz.to/xqxrXpdL/qtproject-zip

I try to call public slot from qml

```
Component.onCompleted: print(model.activate())
```

**Still getting error:**

```
TypeError: Property 'activate' of object QQmlDMObjectData(0x7fa35dd89eb0) is not a function
```

If i tried to call the method dynamically from C++, it works:

```
auto item = new TreeItem<MainMenuItem>(new MainMenuItem("kyklop"));

QMetaObject::invokeMethod(item, "activate");
```

If i try to access regular property of my TreeItemTemplateBackend class from qml (for instance level), it works, so problem is only if calling method. I am thinking it could be something with that subclass/template class.

**Registering to qml:**

```
qmlRegisterType<TreeItemTemplateBackend>("engine.ui", 1, 0, "TreeItemTemplateBackend");
qmlRegisterType<TreeItem<InspectorItem>>("engine.ui", 1, 0, "InspectorTreeItem");
qmlRegisterType<TreeItem<MainMenuItem>>("engine.ui", 1, 0, "MainMenuTreeItem");
```

**TreeItem.h**

```
#ifndef TREEITEM_H
#define TREEITEM_H

#include <QObject>
#include "TreeItemTemplateBackend.h"

template <typename T>
class TreeItem :  public TreeItemTemplateBackend
{

public:
    explicit TreeItem(QObject * parent = NULL);
    explicit TreeItem(T * data, QObject * parent = NULL);
    explicit TreeItem(TreeItem<T> & other);
    void addChild(TreeItem<T> * child);
    ~TreeItem() {}
};

#endif // TREEITEM_H
```

**TreeItemTemplateBackend.h**

```
#ifndef TREEITEMTEMPLATEBACKEND_H
#define TREEITEMTEMPLATEBACKEND_H

#include <QList>
#include <QQmlListProperty>

class TreeItemTemplateBackend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QObject * data READ data WRITE setData NOTIFY dataChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<TreeItemTemplateBackend> childs READ childs NOTIFY childsChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int level READ level WRITE setLevel NOTIFY levelChanged)
public:
    explicit TreeItemTemplateBackend(QObject * parent = NULL);
    QObject * data() const;
    void setData(QObject * data);
    QQmlListProperty<TreeItemTemplateBackend> childs() const;
    void addChild(TreeItemTemplateBackend * child);
    int level() const;
    void setLevel(int level);
    void dump(QString propertyName) const;
    ~TreeItemTemplateBackend() {}
signals:
    void activated(); 
    void dataChanged();
    void childsChanged();
    void levelChanged();
public slots:
    void activate(); // this is what i am trying to call
protected:
    QObject * m_data;
    QList<TreeItemTemplateBackend *> m_children;
    int m_level;
    static void append_function(QQmlListProperty<TreeItemTemplateBackend> * property, TreeItemTemplateBackend * item);
    static TreeItemTemplateBackend * at_function(QQmlListProperty<TreeItemTemplateBackend> * property, int index);
    static void clear_function(QQmlListProperty<TreeItemTemplateBackend> * property);
    static int count_function(QQmlListProperty<TreeItemTemplateBackend> * property);
};

#endif // TREEITEMTEMPLATEBACKEND_H
```

Comment: Is you custom type registered to the QML engine?

Comment: @ddriver: yes it is, i modified code to show the registration

Comment: Can you provide a compilable example? For example, a single main.cpp and the QML file?

Comment: @Mitch: i will post zip file with project that i created (it contains just the minimal to show the problem)

Comment: I am not sure, but it probably has to do with the template. Why don't your try scrapping the template and using `QVariant` instead of `T *` for the data, and register needed types to the meta system. Also take a look at this link: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq15-academic.html

Comment: Any name clashes? Try using a different name for the function. Another thing to try is declaring the function in the public section with Q_INVOKABLE  macro. Q_INVOKABLE void activate();

Answer (score 4):

`QQmlDMObjectData` is a wrapper for the actual object used in delegates. The original object is accessible via the property `modelData`, so `model.modelData.activate()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you cal for it "method" and still you are use it as a method so convert it to the method:

```cpp
...
public:
void Q_INVOKABLE activate();
...
```